# git server and username

Tags: git

I have setup git server via ssh (one git account and many different public/private keys). Everything works fine, but I am concerned about security, as everybody may change their name and email, e.g. make a forged commit.

How can I ensure that everybody is committing under their names and not somebody's other name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At work we use [Gerrit](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) to manage our repositories. One of its features is that all communication with Gerrit is done over SSH using public/private key authentication (Gerrit has a built-in SSH server). You can set up the permissions so that normal users can't push commits that have a different committer (or author) name than the one they're logged in with.

The other benefit of using Gerrit, of course, is that you get a really good code review system.

Comment: `(Gerrit has a built-in SSH server)`, a bit confused, ahd what is about sshd, which is used to login into system?

Comment: Gerrit's SSH server runs on a non-default port (29418 in the default configuration) so it does not conflict with the system sshd on port 22.